Type never is not assignable to promise array, boolean and error as value
I have stated the type of the data which I am getting from the server action, and yet I am getting an error saying that it cannot be assigned to a type which have never,
type Package = {
    productName: string;
  };
  
  type BuddyShield = {
    remarks: string | null;
    buddyShieldUploadProof: boolean;
    rtoStarted: Date | null;
  };
  
  type User = {
    fullname: string;
  };
  
  export type OrderSecondSchema = {
    id: number;
    awbNumber: string | null;
    ChannelOrder_Id: string | null;
    deliveryPartner: string | null;
    shippingDate: Date;
    status: OrderStatus;
    Packages: Package[];
    buddyShield: BuddyShield | null;
    Users: User;
  };
  
  export type OrderQueryResult = OrderSecondSchema[];

  export async function getFilteredOrders(filters: OrderFilters)  {
    const { startDate, endDate, partner, page, searchQuery } = filters;
    const itemsPerPage = 10;
    const skip = (page - 1) * itemsPerPage;

    const userIdString = getCurrentUser();

> userIdString, gets the string id.

    const whereClause: any = {
      status: {
        in: ['RTO_IN_TRANSIT', 'RTO_DELIVERED']
      }
    }

    whereClause.usersId = userIdString

    const allOrders : OrderQueryResult = await prisma.orders.findMany({
      where: whereClause,
      select: {
        id: true,
        awbNumber: true,
        ChannelOrder_Id: true,
        deliveryPartner: true,
        shippingDate: true,
        status: true,
        Packages : {
         select: {
          productName: true,
         }
        },
        buddyShield : {
          select: {
            remarks: true,
            buddyShieldUploadProof: true,
            rtoStarted: true,
          }
        },
        Users: {
          select: {
            fullname: true,
          }
        },
      }
    });

    // console.log('Line 81 ', allOrders);
  
    // Apply date and partner filters
    console.log('Line 122 startdate ', startDate, ' enddate ', endDate);
    let filteredOrders = allOrders.filter((order) => {
      const orderDate = new Date(order.shippingDate);
      const dateFilter = 
        (!startDate || orderDate >= new Date(startDate)) &&
        (!endDate || orderDate <= new Date(endDate));
        const partnerFilter = 
        partner === "All" || 
        (order.deliveryPartner?.toLowerCase() ?? "") === partner.toLowerCase();
      return dateFilter && partnerFilter;
    });
  
  
    // Apply fuzzy search if searchQuery is provided
    if (searchQuery) {
      console.log('Line 137 ', searchQuery);
      const fuse = new Fuse(filteredOrders, {
        keys: ['awbNumber'],
        threshold: 0.3,
      });
      filteredOrders = fuse.search(searchQuery).map(result => result.item);
      console.log('Fuse Search ', filteredOrders);
    }
  
    const totalOrders = filteredOrders.length;
    const totalPages = Math.ceil(totalOrders / itemsPerPage);
  
    // Apply pagination
    filteredOrders = filteredOrders.slice(skip, skip + itemsPerPage);
  
    return {
      orders: filteredOrders,
      totalPages,
      currentPage: page,
      totalOrders,
    };
  }

I tried assigning types stating what it will return tried checking the line number where the error occurred ,to see if it is a problem with type or not but was not able to fix it.

Please [edit] your code to be a [mre] that demonstrates your issue when we copy and paste it into our own IDEs. If your question depends on third party or private things like prisma, OrderFilters, getCurrentUser(), etc., then you should add appropriate tags and/or import/declare the types for them. If not, you should remove them from your example and reduce it down to a [mre]. Make sure that you include the exact text of the error and where it occurs in your code (e.g., add an inline comment). Right now this question risks being closed as needing debugging details.

The error is, Property 'getFilteredOrders' is incompatible with index signature.
Type '(filters: OrderFilters) => Promise<{ orders: OrderSecondSchema[]; totalPages: number; currentPage: number; totalOrders: number; }>' is not assignable to type 'never'.// Check that the entry is a valid entry

8 | checkFields<Diff<{
|             ^
9 |   default: Function
10 |   config?: {}
11 |   generateStaticParams?: Function


Sorry, I meant "inline comment" in the code example. This is still not a [mre] and indeed the only edit you made is syntactically invalid code (by "comment" I meant like // xxx or /* xxx */). And there's still stuff like Fuse etc that isn't a [mre]. This question still risks being closed as needing debugging details, unfortunately.

I was facing this problem  in server actions BuddyShield and HighShipping. I had two folder BuddyShield and HighShipping inside which the file page.tsx, that was the problem don't keep the name of the file in server actions as page.tsx, you will get a type error, just name it anything else
